# Error of 'The name 'WebHost' does not exist in the current context'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Ok, so I am getting 2 errors here:

> Error CS1061  'IWebHost' does not contain a definition for 'Run' and no accessible extension method 'Run' accepting a first argument of type 'IWebHost' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  UserWebAPI  C:\Users\cashamerica12345\Documents\UserWebAPI\UserWebAPI\UserWebAPI\Program.cs 17  Active
>
> Error  CS0103  The name 'WebHost' does not exist in the current context    UserWebAPI  C:\Users\cashamerica12345\Documents\UserWebAPI\UserWebAPI\UserWebAPI\Program.cs 21  Active

What I have tried is making sure my Nuget packages are correct and at first I decided to use Microsoft.EntityFramework version 2.1.0 instead of 2.2.6 and soon updated to 2.2.6 and changed in project properties to use .NET Core 2.2, but did not work, so I went back to .NET Core 2.1 and still having this issue. I even tried deleting 'obj' folder and rebuilding solution. Here are my Nuget Packages I am using:

[image]

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace UserWebAPI
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

**IdentityModel.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UserWebAPI.Models
{
    public class IdentityModel
    {
        public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
        {

        }

        public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
        {
            public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
                : base(options)
            {

            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=cashamerica;Initial Catalog=mydbase; Integrated Security=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using UserWebAPI.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace UserWebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        //This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The method is called Start(), not Run(). Asuming it is this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhost?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Well, I was expecting Run, but I tried Start, it got rid of the first error, but still says WebHost does not exist

Comment: A static class called "WebHost" (wich you appear to be referencing) indeed seems to be unique to .NET Core, 2.0 and later. However there are cases where the Compiler trips up so heavily trying to interpret what you give it, it can not even tell you anymore where the real issue is. This happens in particulary if you got some missing or extra `;` or `{}`. Considering you wrote out the code, why do you even use the Lambda syntax? Why not simply make it a bog-standartt function?

Comment: I am using 'Microsoft.AspNetCore', isn't this where WebHost comes from? I did not write out the code, I just created a new project of ASP.net Core. So basically I could have an issue somewhere else?

Comment: The namespace and everything else seems correct. Wich makes me think there is some serious Compiler Interpretion messup. As that is a lot of code in what is effectively a single line, I would bet on that CreateWebHostBuilder Function. Make it a normal function and add a Temporary variable after each step. That should help you figure out wich part has the issue.

Comment: Ok, I posted the rest of my code, I am kind of curious how I would make it a normal function.

Comment: If the Syntax error points at the Programm.cs, I would asume it is actually there. And turning that function into a non-lambda one with tempirary variables should look like this: `public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args){ 
 var temp1 = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
 var temp2 = temp1.UseStartup<Startup>();
 var temp3 = temp2.Build();
 return temp3;
}` (of course with a newline after each semikolon. Comments just do not do newlines).

Comment: I have a red underling on `WebHost` when using temporary variables like you said. Says "The name Webhost does not exist in the current context".

Comment: I don't think you should be calling `Build` twice, for one thing - your `CreateWebHostBuilder` method claims to return an `IWebHostBuilder`, but since you're calling `Build` inside isn't it actually returning a built `IWebHost`?

Comment: I have no idea why the interpreation would end up at that result. Maybe something broke and a clean rebuild of the Project is needed? In the end, VS is just a programm too after all. It can bug out as well. Unfortunately I do not have a installation running around to cross test it. But crgoldens idea also holsd some merit. Maybe the tripup happens when you call a (illegal) Build above?

Comment: I did try clean solution > Rebuild solution, did not work. However, I try closing visual studio and opening it again, but still has this issue.

Comment: here is link: https://github.com/alextech1/UserWebAPI

Comment: moment, I think I am having upload issue.. Controllers folder missing

Comment: ok, it seems like github doesnt upload folders that are empty, so it did upload.

Comment: You are right, I do not need to call Build() a second time on IWebHostBuilder, that was just there because the asp.net core new project comes with webpage built in, but I removed those webpages as they are not needed. Although, I removed it, I am still having this issue.  My main goal is to run Startup.

Comment: You need a *package reference* to `Microsoft.AspNetCore` for `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`, although it is recommended to just use the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-2.2) metapackage as of 2.1.

Comment: Yes I see now, I didn't see any red line on it, which made it hard to understand why. But now I get it.